# Android - EditText's hint changes View/Layout's size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have a LinearLayout consisting of 3 LinearLayout's consisting of 2 TextView's and an EditText. When I add a hint to the third EditText I end up with a lot of whitespace between the 2nd and 3rd TextViews and also after the 3rd.

Code and images are below. What could be causing this?

```
        <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/self"
        >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="22sp"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Name"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/self_name_show"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#0099CC"
            />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/self_name_edit"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/enter_name"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="22sp"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Address"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/self_address_show"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#0099CC"
            />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/self_address_edit"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/enter_address"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/phone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:autoLink="all"
                android:textSize="22sp"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sample Phone"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/self_phone_show"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textColor="#0099CC"
            />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/self_phone_edit"
                android:phoneNumber="true"
                android:hint="@string/enter_phone"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/edit"
            android:id="@+id/edit_self_button"
            android:onClick="toggleSelfEdit"
        />
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/update"
            android:id="@+id/update_self_button"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Without hint:
[image: Without hint:]

With hint:
[image: With hint:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot writing the `android:visibility="gone"` at the third edittext. I tried your xml and when I put visibility="gone" inside the edittext your xml looks like the first screenshot :)

Comment: I guess it was taking up zero space before the hint was applied, requiring the visibility to be manually set afterwards.

Comment: Yes I agree. Another solution is declaring your editview's height is directly like 20dp in your code not wrap_content. Hint text size may cause that problem.